# Navigation stack tutorial: move_base crashes: bad_alloc thrown, gdb output attached

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This is a question that is related to

http://answers.ros.org/question/3800/error-on-navstack-with-p3dx-robot-aborting-because

It is a follow-up in the sense that in the previous question I proposed to use AMCL and a pre-made map as in the ROS tutorials. In the previous question, I was not using a pre-made map. I was using Gmapping and making the map as I went along. This time I am running AMCL, pretty similar to the tutorial described in:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

While following this tutorial, the move_base node dies even before I send a navigation goal. Upon searching ROS-Answers for similar questions, I came across

http://answers.ros.org/question/316/move_base-node-dies-cant-tell-why

where the solution was investigated by running gdb and running a back trace. I have attempted the same, and the results of the back trace are attached.

### My Procedure

1. Run Motor drivers
2. Run Laser drivers
3. Run relevant transforms
4. Run pre-made map through map server. [Map](http://www.2shared.com/file/of5o4m7n /ltlobby.html) [YAML](http://pastebin.com/ZQWamKbQ)
5. Run Navigation : [Launch file](http://pastebin.com/CXLiANQr) , [costmap_common_params](http://pastebin.com/D6mv07Zi) , [local_costmap_params](http://pastebin.com/k7XVVDGk) , [global_costmap_params](http://pastebin.com/MWpQcvQR) , [base_local_planner](http://pastebin.com/dSvucNZ3) .

After a few seconds, the terminal where I run the navigation launch file crashes. Here is the output of that terminal along with the gdb backtrace : [output with backtrace](http://pastebin.com/SBWMDsuz)

### Other Relevant Data

- Here are the tf frames: [frames.pdf](http://www.2shared.com/document/vxw_iu3b/frames.html)
- Here is the rxgraph: [http://tinypic.com/r/1621gmb/5](http://tinypic.com/r/1621gmb/5%5D)
- Here is the rxgraph with all topics: http://tinypic.com/r/30vbqbo/5

I hope this information is sufficient. Please ask me anything else that you might require.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12904/navigation-stack-tutorial:-move_base-crashes:-bad_alloc-thrown,-gdb-output-attached/) by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would run `top` while you try to run this program to see how much of your system memory you are consuming. You're using a 4000x4000 pixel map, so this could easily use the majority of your RAM. Maybe I read it wrong, but it looked like you loaded this map more than once in the backtrace. This could explain your problem.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) on 2012-02-06**:
I can see what you mean. However, I only used the command "rosrun map_server map_server *.yaml" once and before running the navigation launch file. I will try running top and see if it is because I'm using such a large map. Perhaps I could also make the map smaller? I'm not sure how, but i'll try.

**Comment by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) on 2012-02-21**:
Thanks for your answer Dimitri, it was indeed because the default parameters for gmapping, create a map that starts with 200X200 m. Ofcourse it is possible to change the start size of the map using gmapping parameters (xmin, ymax etc.). A small starting map size worked. Thanks!